# How do I update my html on Click in Angularjs Controllers

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs

I have the html Structure that I need to update from the json data. My Json data is in a Controller. I need to write an expression for ng-click event that will read the json data and put the in the corresponding div in html. but I am not sure how to acheive  this.

Below is what I have so far.

```
<body data-ng-app>
    <div class="container" data-ng-controller="UpdateDataCtrl">
        <div class="inner1"></div>
        <div class="inner2"></div>
    </div>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="not sure how to get json here">UPdate Controllers</a>
</body>


function UpdateDataCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.data = [
            {
                "USA":"Eglish",
                "Pop":"232423432432"
            },
            {
                "France":"French",
                "Pop":"1212323432"
            },
            {
                "Spain":"Spainish",
                "Pop":"3432432"
            }
        ]
    }
```

On each click the 2 Div should get updated from the json. First div should have USA---English Pop---2342234232 and then on next click the div should have data from France and so on.

http://jsfiddle.net/MBFpD/1/

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are unclear on the concept of AngularjS. You don't want to update the DIVs. You want to reference your model and then change the data in your model.

For example you can write the div like this:

```
<div class="inner1">Population: {{data[dataindex].Pop}}</div>
```

Then in the Controller you initialize the dataindex to 0, so that this will output the population from the first entry in the array:

```
$scope.dataindex = 0;
```

The click function (you must have the link with the ng:click inside the block governed by the Controller!) could then just increase the dataindex by one and by using modulo restart at 0 again when the end of the array was reached.

```
$scope.click = function() {
  $scope.dataindex = ($scope.dataindex+1) % $scope.data.length;
```

Here is an updated and modified jsfiddle of your example which will show everything in action: http://jsfiddle.net/MBFpD/2/

Comment: thanks thats useful. what is dataindex. Is this a keyword in angularjs?

Comment: No, it is just another variable which is used as the array index and then incremented on click.

Comment: thanks, I owe a treat to you...

is this how you define vars in angular  $scope.dataindex = 0;

Comment: @Mike - I highly recommend you take an hour or two and go through the AngularJS getting started tutorial @ http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial. It's interactive and will answer a lot of your questions.

Comment: The angularjs tutorial videos at egghead.io are a good resource as well.

Comment: @kju: what does this expression do 
 $scope.dataindex = ($scope.dataindex+1)%($scope.data.length);
I didnt understand what % is in angularjs

Comment: This is not angular-specific but simply JavaScript. % is the modulo operator (returning the remainder of a division). 0 % 3 is 0, 1 % 3 is 1, 2 % 3 is 2, 3 % 3 is 0, 4 % 3 is 1 and so on.

Comment: Thanks, I know that but I was trying to simplify the expression. Though I got the data but I am not able to update the html with that?
Can you please check
http://jsfiddle.net/MBFpD/24/

Comment: If you want to do it like this, you still have to set the values on the scope. See http://jsfiddle.net/MBFpD/28/

Answer (score 0):

Bind your data to your scope when you click on the link:

```
$scope.update = function() {
  $scope.data = data; //your array defined locally to the scope
};
```

`ng-repeat` your data bound to the scope; display the container if the size of the array is > 0.

Use `{{index}}` to get the iteration variable inside the loop.

Above all, move your `ng-controller` declarative at the top to enclose both your `ng-repeat` and your `ng-click`; otherwise, AngularJS cannot guess what you want to achieve.

**http://jsfiddle.net/MBFpD/5/**